# Limitation, restriction vs constraint

Tags: word-choice

Suppose you are talking to one of the government officials. You ask them: "why the project X is not done yet?" He wants to explain and bring some excuses. He tends to tell you that there have been some issues that you are not aware of them; which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you:

> - unfortunately, there have been lots of **limitations** in this respect.
> - unfortunately, there have been lots of **restrictions** in this respect.
> - unfortunately, there have been lots of **constraints** in this respect.

Here you can see why dictionary definitions are not clear and most of the times helpful:
[Limitation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/limitation), [Restriction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/restriction), [Constraint](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/constraint)

Meanwhile, please let me know a bit more about these words. How they differ in meaning and how shall I know when one can use each one?

The only thing that I know, is that "limitation" talks about general inability whereas "restriction" tends to talk more about something forced by regulations or government or etc. But I have no idea about "constraint".

Comment: **issues** sounds better than any of your three suggestions. The **in this respect** may refer to some particular kind of problem, and each of your suggestions may work well for a particular kind of problem. For example: Government regulation specify that the work must not be carried out night, therefore our working hours are **limted**. Or, the water sources we use are subject to **restrictions**, we may not take more than X gallons per day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in thinking a "limitation" is an inability for *something/someone*

> His job choices are *limited* by not being able to read.

and a "restriction" is externally imposed to stop *something*, usually by law

> The area is *restricted* to authorised personnel only.
>   There is a speed *restriction* for how fast you may drive in a residential area.

Both "limitations" and "restrictions" are "constraints" which can be the more encompassing term to describe *something* that stops a person or process from happening.  "Limitations" and "constraints" usually have the feeling of *holding back*, where as "constraints" has the feeling of *holding within*.

Imagine an example of a grazing field fenced in by barbed wire with mountains on the west:

> The cattle grazing is *limited* by the mountain range to the west.
>   The cattle grazing is *restricted* to the 1,000 acres of grazing field.
>   The cattle grazing is *constrained* to the area within the barbed wire fence.

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [fineartamerica.com](http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/cattle-grazing-in-wyoming-antonia-citrino.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Great distinction Peter. Thank you very much. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the Incident Command System we talk about both Limitations and Constraints, both may hinder our efforts if not properly identified and managed.

Hence, a Limitation is something over which the organization has no control, i.e.- weather, whereas,

A Constraint is a self imposed control by the organization, i.e.- for safety reasons we will not work during dark/nighttime hours.

Years late, but wanted to add to the record.